# how to enable frames

Tags: java, android-studio, mediawiki, javadoc

I generated some `javadoc` from `Android Studio` ide. It displays just fine on my local machine. When I put the web code on a remote server (which is a mediawiki), I get a blank page and I think this is related to frame enabling.

The code looks like that

```
<frameset cols="20%,80%" title="Documentation frame" onload="top.loadFrames()">
<frameset rows="30%,70%" title="Left frames" onload="top.loadFrames()">
<frame src="overview-frame.html" name="packageListFrame" title="All Packages">
```

On my console, because I got `Refused to display 'mywebsite/javadoc.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY', I tried to set the mediawiki config variable`[$wgEdi‌​tPageFrameOptions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEditPageFrameOptions)`. I set this variable to`SAMEORIGIN`, but it didn't work

What can I do to display the content ?

Comment: Frames are a feature of HTML; there is nothing to "enable".  Use the browser console to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: that's what I checked on my console, because I got `Refused to display 'mywebsite/javadoc.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.` So I found `https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEditPageFrameOptions` this and I adapted the configuration of the mediawiki, but it didn't work

Comment: So you're actually asking how to adjust that header for your server. You should say that in your question.  Check your server settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is not a Mediawiki, but your web-server (who serves `mywebsite/javadoc.html`) is returning `X-Frame-Options: DENY`, by this reason there is no sense in changing `$wgEditPageFrameOptions` variable (it controls situations when you're embedding Mediawiki page into external site using iframe).

To solve this you can put `.htaccess` file into your `mywebsite` directory ( where `javadoc.html` file located ) with contents below:

`Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`

or, in case your javadoc and mediawiki hosted at different domains:

`Header set X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM my-mediawiki-url.com`

where `my-mediawiki-url.com` is domain of your wiki

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your localsettings.php
right below the line that says

## Path to the GNU diff3 utility.

```
$wgBreakFrames = true;
```